# How to add HTTP header in swiftui and how to get data from json?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm making an application that translates languages by using KakaoTalk api. I added header on url and sent http GET request to get the data from json.. but I can't get the data. I don't know what is wrong..
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQtnu.png

```
      struct QuoteData: Decodable {
          var translated_text: [String]
        }
        struct ContentView: View {
          @State var quotedata: QuoteData?
          var body: some View {
            Button("get"){self.getData())
            Text(quotedata?.translated_text[0] ?? "아니")
          }
          func getData() {
            let token = "8995e2de40ee9b465734713e5a0d2ac5"
            guard let url = URL(string: "https://dapi.kakao.com/v2/translation/translate?src_lang=en&target_lang=kr&query=cotton") else {
              fatalError("Invalid URL")
            }
            var request = URLRequest(url: url)
            request.httpMethod = "GET"
            request.setValue("KakaoAK\(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
              guard let data = data else{ return }
              if let decodedData = try? JSONDecoder().decode(QuoteData.self, from: data){
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                  self.quotedata = decodedData
                }
              }
            }.resume()
          }
        }
```

Comment: What is the error? Where are you calling getData() method? As a good practice keep network login decoupled from UI.

Comment: sorry... I added button code. I want that data is displayed when button is clicked.. There is no error but i cannot get any data.. do you know what is wrong..?

Comment: As always, never ignore DecodingErrors with `try?`, `catch` them and `print` them.

Comment: I have tested your code, and I am facing 401 unauthorized error. That’s why if let condition never executes, as data isn’t decodable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!!.. request.setValue("KakaoAK\(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization") <- i think this code is something wrong.. how can i fix it.. how can i add header on url to get json data..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your token value is space separated `KakaoAK 8995e2de40ee9b465734713e5a0d2ac5`, you have to pass it the same way in your request header, else you will face ***401 unauthorized*** error.

Also, the response is of type `[[String]]` for key `"translated_text`”, and not `[String]`.

Below is the working code-:

```
import SwiftUI


struct QuoteData: Decodable {
    var translated_text: [[String]]
}

struct Test: View {
    @State var quotedata: QuoteData?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Button("get") {
                self.getData()
            }
            Text(quotedata?.translated_text[0][0] ?? "아니")
        }
    }
    
    func getData() {
        let token = "8995e2de40ee9b465734713e5a0d2ac5"
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://dapi.kakao.com/v2/translation/translate?src_lang=en&target_lang=kr&query=cotton") else {
            fatalError("Invalid URL")
        }
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.setValue("KakaoAK \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data else{ return }
            do{
                let decodedData =  try JSONDecoder().decode(QuoteData.self, from: data)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.quotedata = decodedData
                }
            }catch let error{
                print(error)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: i really appreciate you!! thank you!! you are smartest man i have ever seen!!! really appreciate it!! how can i pay you.. i am beginner developer..

Comment: @Jamong25 It’s ok, and thank you for kind words, these things are basics and you will learn them slowly by time good luck.

Answer (score 0):

For those who want to use the new Async Await pattern, I used this which worked great!

```
static func fetchContact(urlString: String) async throws -> Contact {
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
        throw FetchError.invalidURL
    }
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.setValue(Functions().api, forHTTPHeaderField: "ACCESS_TOKEN")
// Functions().api is just a private string that stores the api key
    let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)        
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Contact.self, from: data)
    return result
}
enum FetchError: Error {
    case invalidURL
    case missingData
}
```

I can call the above with this:

```
let contact = try await Functions.fetchContact(urlString: "https://api.crmworkspace.com/v1/contacts/\(id)")
```

In SwiftUI I call call this function from a view:

```
func call(phone: String, id: Int) async {
    if let url = URL(string: "tel:\(phone.numbersOnly)") {
        await UIApplication.shared.open(url)
        do {
            let contact = try await Functions.fetchContact(urlString: "https://api.crmworkspace.com/v1/contacts/\(id)")
            // Do whatever with the contact object here...
        } catch {
            print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the part of the view that calls this function:

```
Button(action: {
            Task {
                await Functions().call(phone: result.phoneNumber, id: Int(result.id))
            }
        }, label: {
            Label(result.phoneNumber, systemImage: "phone.circle.fill")
        })
```

I find the new async/await pattern much easier to write and debug than closures! Hope this helps someone.